# setBackground Fabric.js: CORS problems

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, cors, fabricjs

I am working with Fabric.js but I have one problem that I can not understand.

I would like to set the background of a Fabric.js canvas but I get CORS problems.
I have read about how to set background using cors

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('presenterCanvas');
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

src = "http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/overheard/files/2016/12/water-molecule.png"; 

canvas.setBackgroundImage(src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
   crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
   width: canvas.width,
   height: canvas.height,   
   originX: 'left',
   originY: 'top'
});
```

and I get this error:
[image]

You can check the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wikett/uvk8xsjf/

I do not understand why I can use that image in the html, and I can add a Fabric Image into the canvas, but I can not set the Background.
Can anyone help with this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `and I get this error:` - a blank page? **edit** - there it is, how odd .... anyway, CORS restricts people from using other peoples resources that they don't want you to use ...displaying an image is one thing, using it in a canvas is another, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that **you** are asking fabric to load the image with a crossOrigin attribute.

When you set an media element's `crossOrigin` attribute, the server must be correctly set up to accept such requests. Otherwise, it will just err, like in your case.

If you don't want to export it later, or apply some of fabric's filters, you don't need to do it.

```js
canvas.setBackgroundImage(src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
//   crossOrigin: 'anonymous',// Here is your problem
   width: canvas.width,
   height: canvas.height,   
   originX: 'left',
   originY: 'top'
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvk8xsjf/2/)

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido but now if I try to export the canvas to png using canvas.toDataURL(); I get this error:Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
You can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/wikett/uvk8xsjf/5/
Do you know how can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: @EnriqueAparicio, yes, that's what I meant by *If you don't want to export it later*. If you actually want, then you have to set up the server hosting your images properly so that it returns a correct `Allow-Control-Allow-Request: *` header when you do a crossOrigin request, or use [a proxy](http://crossorigin.me/) properly set up, both solutions with the `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` option,  or host the images on your own domain.

Comment: My server is already configured with CORS enable (amazon s3 bucket) but still canvas background throw error like :
    cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions on *displaying* images, but there are restrictions on accessing the data (including pixel values) with JavaScript.

Fabric's background image code reads the pixel data (presumably so it can do manipulations like scaling), so you need permission via CORS if the image comes from another origin.